# SSIS package with Merge statement locking the DB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, database-administration

We have a SSIS package which loads the data from csv files to DB. It only loads the new entries ie if the row already exists in the tables than it doesn't insert it. For this we load the CSV to temp tables for respective schemas and than those are compared with base table and inserted new rows. For this we use Merge statement.

But the problem is many times it locks the entire DB during this process.

Can anyone kindly help to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SSIS package transaction level from "Serializable" (the default) to "Read uncommitted".

This article might help, and you can google for more like it:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/